# Full calendar button event for multiple Full calendar

Tags: javascript, html, css, api, fullcalendar

I have question about Fullcalendar that I am using right now. So what I am doing right now is creating multiple Fullcalendar using the foreach. For example, if the loop goes three times there will be three fullcalendar right? And each of them will have prev and next button. I would like to have an event that will trigger depending on what fullcalendar I click so that I can call the api call to display different event for each of the fullcalendar. Also I gave each of the fullcalendar unique id when it foreach happens.

EXAMPLE:

- FULLCALENDAR -> NEXT/PREV
- FULLCALENDAR1 -> NEXT/PREV <-- Clicking this Next or prev button will call and event using function so I can get the date and pass onto my api call to return json data and rerender this calendar
- FULLCALENDAR2 -> NEXT/PREV

I will post my code below.
As you can see from the code below. I am creating the div tag with classname called "calendarSize" with own unique id and passing the unqiue id to the function called "createBiWeeklyCalendar" and render that calendar.

```
function createBiweeklyCalendar(a) {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById(a);
  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    initialView: "dayGridWeek",
   
  });
  calendar.render();
}

function createLocation(data) {
  data.features.forEach(function (store, i) {
    if (i <= 2) {
      let prop = store.properties;

      let listings = document.getElementById("listings");
      let listing = listings.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
      listing.id = "listing-" + prop.id;
      listing.className = "item";

      let details = listing.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
      let roundedDistance = Math.round(prop.distance * 100) / 100;
      details.innerHTML =
        "<strong>Distance:</strong> " + roundedDistance + " miles ";
      details.innerHTML += "<br/> <strong>Address:</strong> " + prop.address;

      let link = listing.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
      link.className = "fieldOffice";
      link.innerHTML = "<strong>Field Office:</strong> " + prop.name;
      link.innerHTML +=
        "<br/><button onClick='callToModal(\"" +
        prop.code +
        "\");return false;' class='btn mini red-stripe' role='button'>Notes</button>";
      link.innerHTML +=
        '<div id="' + prop.code + '" class="calendarSize")></div>';
      createBiweeklyCalendar(prop.code);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Let's go back a step...why do you need 3 calendars on one page??! Why not just have one 3 calendar with 3 event sources? The you can toggle them on and off if you need to display each source separately.

Comment: @ADyson Thats because the calendars sometime can be more than 3 or less. I rewrote the code to react but still having the same problem... But thank you though

Comment: `Thats because the calendars sometime can be more than 3 or less...` well then you could have a variable number of event sources in a single calendar, in just the same way. It's not clear what point you're trying to make with that comment?

Comment: @ADyson I figured it out!! I'm sorry if my question was not clear enough..